# How can I execute a CORBA and python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dockerfile, corba, omniorb

I have a homework from my university, and basically i have to exec the code of a tic tac toe game in this site : https://www.grisby.org/presentations/py10code.html . In this site i have the idl file, the code of client and the code of the server. My problem is NOTHING works for execute this code; i tried use a anaconda environment and the last i make a Dockerfile for execute, but still not working.

When I try to execute the server code this happen:
`*`     File "gameServer.py", line 8, in 
import CORBA, PortableServer, CosNaming
ImportError: No module named CORBA`*`

But I installed the omniORB and omniORBpy and still doesn't work.
I tried install ansys_corba package, and does'nt work too.

This is my Dockerfile:
`    FROM ubuntu:18.04

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python2.7 && \
    apt-get install -y omniidl omniorb omniorb-nameserver &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV ORBINIT_REF=NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService

WORKDIR /app

COPY gameClient.py /app/
COPY gameServer.py /app/
COPY tictactoe.idl /app/

EXPOSE 2809

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]`
```

Some tutorials ask to install the omniidl-python and python-omniorb. But this packages don't are enabled for download anymore.

Any type of help will be really helpful.